# Oracle Apex Pl/SQL - Canonical String from JSON Format

Tags: json, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I am using Oracle Apex 22.2 and Oracle Database XE 21c on CentOS 7. I want to loop through all the nested elements in a JSON document/CLOB and achieve the Canonical String (shown below). Also, any suggestions on improving my procedure or on a different solution to handle this would be appreciated. I wrote my own procedure shown below following the algorithm shown below. All help and suggestions are really appreciated.

**Algorithm Pseudo Code**

```
function string Serialize(documentStructure)
    
    if documentStructure is simple value type
        return """ + documentStructure.value + """
    end if

    var serializedString = ""
    
    foreach element in the structure:
        
        if element is not array type
            serializeString.Append (""" + element.name.uppercase + """)
            serializeString.Append ( Serialize(element.value) )
        end if

        if element is of array type
            serializeString.Append (""" + element.name.uppercase + """)
            foreach array element in element: 
                // use below line for JSON because subelements of array in JSON do not have own names
                serializeString.Append (""" + element.name.uppercase + """)         
                serializeString.Append ( Serialize(arrayelement.value) )              
            end foreach
        end if

    end foreach

    return serializedString
end function
```

**Procedure Code**

```
create or replace PROCEDURE ETA_JSON_SERIALIZE (json_in IN JSON_ELEMENT_T, can_str IN OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
    l_object    JSON_OBJECT_T;
    l_array     JSON_ARRAY_T;
    l_keys      JSON_KEY_LIST;
    l_str       VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1 .. json_in.get_Size LOOP
        IF json_in.is_Scalar() THEN
            IF json_in.is_String() THEN
                l_str := '"' || json_in.to_String() || '" 1st Line Break' || CHR(10);
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_str);
                RETURN;
            ELSIF json_in.is_Number() THEN
                l_str := '"' || json_in.to_Number() || '" 2nd Line Break' || CHR(10);
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_str);
                RETURN;
            ELSE
                l_str := 'Other Scalar' || ' 3rd Line Break' || CHR(10);
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_str);
            END IF;
        ELSIF json_in.is_Object() THEN
            -- l_str := 'Object:' || CHR(10);
            -- DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_str);
            l_object := JSON_OBJECT_T( json_in );
            -- l_object.on_Error(1);
            l_keys := l_object.get_Keys();
            -- l_str := '     Element Size: ' || json_in.get_Size || CHR(10);
            -- l_str := '     Key Count: ' || l_keys.COUNT || CHR(10);
            -- DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_str);
            l_str := UPPER(l_keys(i)) || ' 4th Line Break' || CHR(10);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_str);
            ETA_JSON_SERIALIZE( l_object.get( l_keys(i) ), l_str );
        ELSIF json_in.is_Array() THEN
            -- l_str := l_str || 'Array:' || CHR(10);
            -- DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_str);
            l_array := JSON_ARRAY_T( json_in );
            -- l_array.on_Error(1);
            -- l_str := '     Element Size: ' || json_in.get_Size || CHR(10);
            -- DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_str);
            -- l_str := '     Array Size: ' || l_array.get_Size || CHR(10);
            -- DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_str);
            -- FOR j IN 0 .. l_array.get_Size - 1 LOOP
                ETA_JSON_SERIALIZE( l_array.get(i - 1), l_str );
            -- END LOOP;
        ELSE
            l_str := 'Other Type' || CHR(10)  || '5th Line Break' || CHR(10);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_str);
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    can_str := l_str;
END;
```

**PL/SQL Block**

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
   can_str     VARCHAR2(32767);
   l_element   JSON_ELEMENT_T;
   l_element1  JSON_ELEMENT_T;
   l_object    JSON_OBJECT_T;
   l_keys      JSON_KEY_LIST;
   l_doc       CLOB := '{a:100, b:200, c:300}';
   l_doc1      CLOB := '{
   "department": "Accounting",
   "employees": [
   {
   "name": "Shelley,Higgins",
   "job": "Accounting Manager"
   },
   {
   "name": "William,Gietz",
   "job": "Public Accountant"
   }
   ]
   }';

   l_doc2      CLOB := '{
   "REQS": {
   "INDICATOR": "Y",
   "NUMBER": 0,
   "CATEGORY": "TU",
   "ID_R": 10888,
   "SUPPL_VAL": 0,
   "LINE_ITEMSSUB": {
   "QTY": 0,
   "TOTAL_QTY": 1,
   "PIPE": {
   "P_CODE": 9801,
   "P_ID": 7500030,
   "CC_CODE": "C6AJG4"
   }
   }
   },
   "Name": "Rajesh",
   "Age": 47
   }';
   l_doc3      CLOB := '{
   "documents": [{
      "issuer": {
         "type": "B",
         "id": "301188475",
         "name": "Hakim Misr Paco (POS-0)",
         "address": {
            "branchID": "-1",
            "country": "EG",
            "governate": "Cairo",
            "regionCity": "Nasr City",
            "street": "Mostafa El Nahas",
            "buildingNumber": "65"
         }
      },
      "receiver": {
         "type": "P",
         "id": " 29409200104255",
         "name": "Karim Ahmed Abdelhakim Hashem",
         "address": {
            "country": "EG",
            "governate": "Cairo",
            "regionCity": "Nasr City",
            "street": "Mostafa El Nahas",
            "buildingNumber": "65"
         }
      },
      "documentType": "I",
      "documentTypeVersion": "0.9",
      "dateTimeIssued": "2022-11-19T23:59:59Z",
      "taxpayerActivityCode": "2220",
      "internalID": "0-1",
      "invoiceLines": [{
         "description": "KFC_Test",
         "itemType": "GS1",
         "itemCode": "10006331",
         "unitType": "EA",
         "quantity": 1000,
         "unitValue": {
            "currencySold": "EGP",
            "amountEGP": 0.10000,
            "amountSold": 0
         },
         "salesTotal": 100,
         "total": 114,
         "valueDifference": 0,
         "totalTaxableFees": 0,
         "netTotal": 100,
         "itemsDiscount": 0,
         "discount": {
            "rate": 0,
            "amount": 0
         },
         "taxableItems": [{
            "taxType": "T1",
            "amount": 14,
            "subType": "V009",
            "rate": 14
         }],
         "internalCode": "Test_110"
      }],
      "totalSalesAmount": 100,
      "totalDiscountAmount": 0,
      "netAmount": 100,
      "taxTotals": [{
         "taxType": "T1",
         "amount": 14
      }],
      "extraDiscountAmount": 0,
      "totalItemsDiscountAmount": 0,
      "totalAmount": 114,
      "signatures": [{
         "signatureType": "I",
         "value": "NA"
      }]
   }]
}';

BEGIN 
   l_element := JSON_ELEMENT_T.parse( l_doc3 );
   ETA_JSON_SERIALIZE(l_element, can_str);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(can_str);
END;
/
```

**JSON Format**

```
<pre>
{
    "issuer": {
        "address": {
            "branchID": "1",
            "country": "EG",
            "governate": "Cairo",
            "regionCity": "Nasr City",
            "street": "580 Clementina Key",
            "buildingNumber": "Bldg. 0",
            "postalCode": "68030",
            "floor": "1",
            "room": "123",
            "landmark": "7660 Melody Trail",
            "additionalInformation": "beside Townhall"
        },
        "type": "B",
        "id": "113317713",
        "name": "Issuer Company"
    },
    "receiver": {
        "address": {
            "country": "EG",
            "governate": "Egypt",
            "regionCity": "Mufazat al Ismlyah",
            "street": "580 Clementina Key",
            "buildingNumber": "Bldg. 0",
            "postalCode": "68030",
            "floor": "1",
            "room": "123",
            "landmark": "7660 Melody Trail",
            "additionalInformation": "beside Townhall"
        },
        "type": "B",
        "id": "313717919",
        "name": "Receiver"
    },
    "documentType": "I",
    "documentTypeVersion": "0.9",
    "dateTimeIssued": "2020-10-27T23:59:59Z",
    "taxpayerActivityCode": "4620",
    "internalID": "IID1",
    "purchaseOrderReference": "P-233-A6375",
    "purchaseOrderDescription": "purchase Order description",
    "salesOrderReference": "1231",
    "salesOrderDescription": "Sales Order description",
    "proformaInvoiceNumber": "SomeValue",
    "payment": {
        "bankName": "SomeValue",
        "bankAddress": "SomeValue",
        "bankAccountNo": "SomeValue",
        "bankAccountIBAN": "",
        "swiftCode": "",
        "terms": "SomeValue"
    },
    "delivery": {
        "approach": "SomeValue",
        "packaging": "SomeValue",
        "dateValidity": "2020-09-28T09:30:10Z",
        "exportPort": "SomeValue",
        "countryOfOrigin": "EG",
        "grossWeight": 10.50,
        "netWeight": 20.50,
        "terms": "SomeValue"
    },
    "invoiceLines": [
        {
            "description": "Computer1",
            "itemType": "GPC",
            "itemCode": "10001774",
            "unitType": "EA",
            "quantity": 5,
            "internalCode": "IC0",
            "salesTotal": 947.00,
            "total": 2969.89,
            "valueDifference": 7.00,
            "totalTaxableFees": 817.42,
            "netTotal": 880.71,
            "itemsDiscount": 5.00,
            "unitValue": {
                "currencySold": "EUR",
                "amountEGP": 189.40,
                "amountSold": 10.00,
                "currencyExchangeRate": 18.94
            },
            "discount": {
                "rate": 7,
                "amount": 66.29
            },
            "taxableItems": [
                {
                    "taxType": "T1",
                    "amount": 272.07,
                    "subType": "T1",
                    "rate": 14.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T2",
                    "amount": 208.22,
                    "subType": "T2",
                    "rate": 12
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T3",
                    "amount": 30.00,
                    "subType": "T3",
                    "rate": 0.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T4",
                    "amount": 43.79,
                    "subType": "T4",
                    "rate": 5.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T5",
                    "amount": 123.30,
                    "subType": "T5",
                    "rate": 14.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T6",
                    "amount": 60.00,
                    "subType": "T6",
                    "rate": 0.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T7",
                    "amount": 88.07,
                    "subType": "T7",
                    "rate": 10.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T8",
                    "amount": 123.30,
                    "subType": "T8",
                    "rate": 14.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T9",
                    "amount": 105.69,
                    "subType": "T9",
                    "rate": 12.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T10",
                    "amount": 88.07,
                    "subType": "T10",
                    "rate": 10.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T11",
                    "amount": 123.30,
                    "subType": "T11",
                    "rate": 14.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T12",
                    "amount": 105.69,
                    "subType": "T12",
                    "rate": 12.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T13",
                    "amount": 88.07,
                    "subType": "T13",
                    "rate": 10.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T14",
                    "amount": 123.30,
                    "subType": "T14",
                    "rate": 14.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T15",
                    "amount": 105.69,
                    "subType": "T15",
                    "rate": 12.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T16",
                    "amount": 88.07,
                    "subType": "T16",
                    "rate": 10.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T17",
                    "amount": 88.07,
                    "subType": "T17",
                    "rate": 10.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T18",
                    "amount": 123.30,
                    "subType": "T18",
                    "rate": 14.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T19",
                    "amount": 105.69,
                    "subType": "T19",
                    "rate": 12.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T20",
                    "amount": 88.07,
                    "subType": "T20",
                    "rate": 10.00
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "description": "Computer2",
            "itemType": "GPC",
            "itemCode": "10003752",
            "unitType": "EA",
            "quantity": 7,
            "internalCode": "IC0",
            "salesTotal": 662.90,
            "total": 2226.61,
            "valueDifference": 6.00,
            "totalTaxableFees": 621.51,
            "netTotal": 652.90,
            "itemsDiscount": 9.00,
            "unitValue": {
                "currencySold": "EUR",
                "amountEGP": 94.70,
                "amountSold": 5.00,
                "currencyExchangeRate": 18.94
            },
            "discount": {
                "rate": 0,
                "amount": 10.00
            },
            "taxableItems": [
                {
                    "taxType": "T1",
                    "amount": 205.47,
                    "subType": "T1",
                    "rate": 14.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T2",
                    "amount": 157.25,
                    "subType": "T2",
                    "rate": 12
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T3",
                    "amount": 30.00,
                    "subType": "T3",
                    "rate": 0.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T4",
                    "amount": 32.20,
                    "subType": "T4",
                    "rate": 5.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T5",
                    "amount": 91.41,
                    "subType": "T5",
                    "rate": 14.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T6",
                    "amount": 60.00,
                    "subType": "T6",
                    "rate": 0.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T7",
                    "amount": 65.29,
                    "subType": "T7",
                    "rate": 10.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T8",
                    "amount": 91.41,
                    "subType": "T8",
                    "rate": 14.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T9",
                    "amount": 78.35,
                    "subType": "T9",
                    "rate": 12.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T10",
                    "amount": 65.29,
                    "subType": "T10",
                    "rate": 10.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T11",
                    "amount": 91.41,
                    "subType": "T11",
                    "rate": 14.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T12",
                    "amount": 78.35,
                    "subType": "T12",
                    "rate": 12.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T13",
                    "amount": 65.29,
                    "subType": "T13",
                    "rate": 10.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T14",
                    "amount": 91.41,
                    "subType": "T14",
                    "rate": 14.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T15",
                    "amount": 78.35,
                    "subType": "T15",
                    "rate": 12.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T16",
                    "amount": 65.29,
                    "subType": "T16",
                    "rate": 10.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T17",
                    "amount": 65.29,
                    "subType": "T17",
                    "rate": 10.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T18",
                    "amount": 91.41,
                    "subType": "T18",
                    "rate": 14.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T19",
                    "amount": 78.35,
                    "subType": "T19",
                    "rate": 12.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T20",
                    "amount": 65.29,
                    "subType": "T20",
                    "rate": 10.00
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "totalDiscountAmount": 76.29,
    "totalSalesAmount": 1609.90,
    "netAmount": 1533.61,
    "taxTotals": [
        {
            "taxType": "T1",
            "amount": 477.54
        },
        {
            "taxType": "T2",
            "amount": 365.47
        },
        {
            "taxType": "T3",
            "amount": 60.00
        },
        {
            "taxType": "T4",
            "amount": 75.99
        },
        {
            "taxType": "T5",
            "amount": 214.71
        },
        {
            "taxType": "T6",
            "amount": 120.00
        },
        {
            "taxType": "T7",
            "amount": 153.36
        },
        {
            "taxType": "T8",
            "amount": 214.71
        },
        {
            "taxType": "T9",
            "amount": 184.04
        },
        {
            "taxType": "T10",
            "amount": 153.36
        },
        {
            "taxType": "T11",
            "amount": 214.71
        },
        {
            "taxType": "T12",
            "amount": 184.04
        },
        {
            "taxType": "T13",
            "amount": 153.36
        },
        {
            "taxType": "T14",
            "amount": 214.71
        },
        {
            "taxType": "T15",
            "amount": 184.04
        },
        {
            "taxType": "T16",
            "amount": 153.36
        },
        {
            "taxType": "T17",
            "amount": 153.36
        },
        {
            "taxType": "T18",
            "amount": 214.71
        },
        {
            "taxType": "T19",
            "amount": 184.04
        },
        {
            "taxType": "T20",
            "amount": 153.36
        }
    ],
    "totalAmount": 5191.50,
    "extraDiscountAmount": 5.00,
    "totalItemsDiscountAmount": 14.00
}
```

**Canonical String**

```
    "ISSUER""ADDRESS""BRANCHID""1""COUNTRY""EG""GOVERNATE""Cairo""REGIONCITY""Nasr City""STREET""580 Clementina Key""BUILDINGNUMBER""Bldg. 0""POSTALCODE""68030""FLOOR""1""ROOM""123""LANDMARK""7660 Melody Trail""ADDITIONALINFORMATION""beside Townhall""TYPE""B""ID""113317713""NAME""Issuer Company""RECEIVER""ADDRESS""COUNTRY""EG""GOVERNATE""Egypt""REGIONCITY""Mufazat al Ismlyah""STREET""580 Clementina Key""BUILDINGNUMBER""Bldg. 0""POSTALCODE""68030""FLOOR""1""ROOM""123""LANDMARK""7660 Melody Trail""ADDITIONALINFORMATION""beside Townhall""TYPE""B""ID""313717919""NAME""Receiver""DOCUMENTTYPE""I""DOCUMENTTYPEVERSION""0.9""DATETIMEISSUED""2020-10-27T23:59:59Z""TAXPAYERACTIVITYCODE""4620""INTERNALID""IID1""PURCHASEORDERREFERENCE""P-233-A6375""PURCHASEORDERDESCRIPTION""purchase Order description""SALESORDERREFERENCE""1231""SALESORDERDESCRIPTION""Sales Order description""PROFORMAINVOICENUMBER""SomeValue""PAYMENT""BANKNAME""SomeValue""BANKADDRESS""SomeValue""BANKACCOUNTNO""SomeValue""BANKACCOUNTIBAN""""SWIFTCODE""""TERMS""SomeValue""DELIVERY""APPROACH""SomeValue""PACKAGING""SomeValue""DATEVALIDITY""2020-09-28T09:30:10Z""EXPORTPORT""SomeValue""COUNTRYOFORIGIN""EG""GROSSWEIGHT""10.50""NETWEIGHT""20.50""TERMS""SomeValue""INVOICELINES""INVOICELINES""DESCRIPTION""Computer1""ITEMTYPE""GPC""ITEMCODE""10001774""UNITTYPE""EA""QUANTITY""5""INTERNALCODE""IC0""SALESTOTAL""947.00""TOTAL""2969.89""VALUEDIFFERENCE""7.00""TOTALTAXABLEFEES""817.42""NETTOTAL""880.71""ITEMSDISCOUNT""5.00""UNITVALUE""CURRENCYSOLD""EUR""AMOUNTEGP""189.40""AMOUNTSOLD""10.00""CURRENCYEXCHANGERATE""18.94""DISCOUNT""RATE""7""AMOUNT""66.29""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T1""AMOUNT""272.07""SUBTYPE""T1""RATE""14.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T2""AMOUNT""208.22""SUBTYPE""T2""RATE""12""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T3""AMOUNT""30.00""SUBTYPE""T3""RATE""0.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T4""AMOUNT""43.79""SUBTYPE""T4""RATE""5.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T5""AMOUNT""123.30""SUBTYPE""T5""RATE""14.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T6""AMOUNT""60.00""SUBTYPE""T6""RATE""0.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T7""AMOUNT""88.07""SUBTYPE""T7""RATE""10.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T8""AMOUNT""123.30""SUBTYPE""T8""RATE""14.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T9""AMOUNT""105.69""SUBTYPE""T9""RATE""12.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T10""AMOUNT""88.07""SUBTYPE""T10""RATE""10.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T11""AMOUNT""123.30""SUBTYPE""T11""RATE""14.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T12""AMOUNT""105.69""SUBTYPE""T12""RATE""12.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T13""AMOUNT""88.07""SUBTYPE""T13""RATE""10.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T14""AMOUNT""123.30""SUBTYPE""T14""RATE""14.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T15""AMOUNT""105.69""SUBTYPE""T15""RATE""12.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T16""AMOUNT""88.07""SUBTYPE""T16""RATE""10.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T17""AMOUNT""88.07""SUBTYPE""T17""RATE""10.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T18""AMOUNT""123.30""SUBTYPE""T18""RATE""14.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T19""AMOUNT""105.69""SUBTYPE""T19""RATE""12.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T20""AMOUNT""88.07""SUBTYPE""T20""RATE""10.00""INVOICELINES""DESCRIPTION""Computer2""ITEMTYPE""GPC""ITEMCODE""10003752""UNITTYPE""EA""QUANTITY""7""INTERNALCODE""IC0""SALESTOTAL""662.90""TOTAL""2226.61""VALUEDIFFERENCE""6.00""TOTALTAXABLEFEES""621.51""NETTOTAL""652.90""ITEMSDISCOUNT""9.00""UNITVALUE""CURRENCYSOLD""EUR""AMOUNTEGP""94.70""AMOUNTSOLD""5.00""CURRENCYEXCHANGERATE""18.94""DISCOUNT""RATE""0""AMOUNT""10.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T1""AMOUNT""205.47""SUBTYPE""T1""RATE""14.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T2""AMOUNT""157.25""SUBTYPE""T2""RATE""12""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T3""AMOUNT""30.00""SUBTYPE""T3""RATE""0.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T4""AMOUNT""32.20""SUBTYPE""T4""RATE""5.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T5""AMOUNT""91.41""SUBTYPE""T5""RATE""14.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T6""AMOUNT""60.00""SUBTYPE""T6""RATE""0.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T7""AMOUNT""65.29""SUBTYPE""T7""RATE""10.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T8""AMOUNT""91.41""SUBTYPE""T8""RATE""14.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T9""AMOUNT""78.35""SUBTYPE""T9""RATE""12.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T10""AMOUNT""65.29""SUBTYPE""T10""RATE""10.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T11""AMOUNT""91.41""SUBTYPE""T11""RATE""14.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T12""AMOUNT""78.35""SUBTYPE""T12""RATE""12.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T13""AMOUNT""65.29""SUBTYPE""T13""RATE""10.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T14""AMOUNT""91.41""SUBTYPE""T14""RATE""14.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T15""AMOUNT""78.35""SUBTYPE""T15""RATE""12.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T16""AMOUNT""65.29""SUBTYPE""T16""RATE""10.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T17""AMOUNT""65.29""SUBTYPE""T17""RATE""10.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T18""AMOUNT""91.41""SUBTYPE""T18""RATE""14.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T19""AMOUNT""78.35""SUBTYPE""T19""RATE""12.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T20""AMOUNT""65.29""SUBTYPE""T20""RATE""10.00""TOTALDISCOUNTAMOUNT""76.29""TOTALSALESAMOUNT""1609.90""NETAMOUNT""1533.61""TAXTOTALS""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T1""AMOUNT""477.54""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T2""AMOUNT""365.47""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T3""AMOUNT""60.00""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T4""AMOUNT""75.99""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T5""AMOUNT""214.71""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T6""AMOUNT""120.00""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T7""AMOUNT""153.36""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T8""AMOUNT""214.71""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T9""AMOUNT""184.04""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T10""AMOUNT""153.36""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T11""AMOUNT""214.71""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T12""AMOUNT""184.04""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T13""AMOUNT""153.36""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T14""AMOUNT""214.71""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T15""AMOUNT""184.04""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T16""AMOUNT""153.36""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T17""AMOUNT""153.36""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T18""AMOUNT""214.71""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T19""AMOUNT""184.04""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T20""AMOUNT""153.36""TOTALAMOUNT""5191.50""EXTRADISCOUNTAMOUNT""5.00""TOTALITEMSDISCOUNTAMOUNT""14.00"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
create or replace PROCEDURE ETA_JSON_SERIALIZE (
  json_in    IN     JSON_ELEMENT_T,
  can_str    IN OUT VARCHAR2,
  object_key IN     VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
)
IS
BEGIN
  IF json_in.is_Object() THEN
    DECLARE
      l_object JSON_OBJECT_T := TREAT(json_in AS JSON_OBJECT_T);
      l_keys   JSON_KEY_LIST := l_object.get_Keys();
    BEGIN
      FOR i IN 1 .. l_keys.COUNT LOOP
        can_str := can_str || '"'||UPPER(l_keys(i))||'"';
        ETA_JSON_SERIALIZE(l_object.get(l_keys(i)), can_str, l_keys(i));
      END LOOP;
    END;
  ELSIF json_in.is_Array() THEN
    DECLARE
      l_array JSON_ARRAY_T := TREAT(json_in AS JSON_ARRAY_T);
    BEGIN
      FOR i IN 0 .. l_array.get_size -1 LOOP
        IF i > 0 AND object_key IS NOT NULL THEN
          can_str := can_str || '"'||UPPER(object_key)||'"';
        END IF;
        ETA_JSON_SERIALIZE(l_array.get(i), can_str);
      END LOOP;
    END;
  ELSIF json_in.is_Scalar() THEN
    can_str := can_str || json_in.to_String();
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
DECLARE
   can_str     VARCHAR2(32767);
   l_element   JSON_ELEMENT_T;
   l_doc       CLOB :=  '{
   "documents": [{
      "issuer": {
         "type": "B",
         "id": "301188475",
         "name": "Hakim Misr Paco (POS-0)",
         "address": {
            "branchID": "-1",
            "country": "EG",
            "governate": "Cairo",
            "regionCity": "Nasr City",
            "street": "Mostafa El Nahas",
            "buildingNumber": "65"
         }
      },
      "receiver": {
         "type": "P",
         "id": " 29409200104255",
         "name": "Karim Ahmed Abdelhakim Hashem",
         "address": {
            "country": "EG",
            "governate": "Cairo",
            "regionCity": "Nasr City",
            "street": "Mostafa El Nahas",
            "buildingNumber": "65"
         }
      },
      "documentType": "I",
      "documentTypeVersion": "0.9",
      "dateTimeIssued": "2022-11-19T23:59:59Z",
      "taxpayerActivityCode": "2220",
      "internalID": "0-1",
      "invoiceLines": [{
         "description": "KFC_Test",
         "itemType": "GS1",
         "itemCode": "10006331",
         "unitType": "EA",
         "quantity": 1000,
         "unitValue": {
            "currencySold": "EGP",
            "amountEGP": 0.10000,
            "amountSold": 0
         },
         "salesTotal": 100,
         "total": 114,
         "valueDifference": 0,
         "totalTaxableFees": 0,
         "netTotal": 100,
         "itemsDiscount": 0,
         "discount": {
            "rate": 0,
            "amount": 0
         },
         "taxableItems": [{
            "taxType": "T1",
            "amount": 14,
            "subType": "V009",
            "rate": 14
         }],
         "internalCode": "Test_110"
      }],
      "totalSalesAmount": 100,
      "totalDiscountAmount": 0,
      "netAmount": 100,
      "taxTotals": [{
         "taxType": "T1",
         "amount": 14
      }],
      "extraDiscountAmount": 0,
      "totalItemsDiscountAmount": 0,
      "totalAmount": 114,
      "signatures": [{
         "signatureType": "I",
         "value": "NA"
      }]
   }]
}';
BEGIN 
   ETA_JSON_SERIALIZE(JSON_ELEMENT_T.parse( l_doc ), can_str);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(can_str);
END;
/
```

Outputs:

```
"DOCUMENTS""ISSUER""TYPE""B""ID""301188475""NAME""Hakim Misr Paco (POS-0)""ADDRESS""BRANCHID""-1""COUNTRY""EG""GOVERNATE""Cairo""REGIONCITY""Nasr City""STREET""Mostafa El Nahas""BUILDINGNUMBER""65""RECEIVER""TYPE""P""ID"" 29409200104255""NAME""Karim Ahmed Abdelhakim Hashem""ADDRESS""COUNTRY""EG""GOVERNATE""Cairo""REGIONCITY""Nasr City""STREET""Mostafa El Nahas""BUILDINGNUMBER""65""DOCUMENTTYPE""I""DOCUMENTTYPEVERSION""0.9""DATETIMEISSUED""2022-11-19T23:59:59Z""TAXPAYERACTIVITYCODE""2220""INTERNALID""0-1""INVOICELINES""DESCRIPTION""KFC_Test""ITEMTYPE""GS1""ITEMCODE""10006331""UNITTYPE""EA""QUANTITY"1000"UNITVALUE""CURRENCYSOLD""EGP""AMOUNTEGP"0.10000"AMOUNTSOLD"0"SALESTOTAL"100"TOTAL"114"VALUEDIFFERENCE"0"TOTALTAXABLEFEES"0"NETTOTAL"100"ITEMSDISCOUNT"0"DISCOUNT""RATE"0"AMOUNT"0"TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T1""AMOUNT"14"SUBTYPE""V009""RATE"14"INTERNALCODE""Test_110""TOTALSALESAMOUNT"100"TOTALDISCOUNTAMOUNT"0"NETAMOUNT"100"TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T1""AMOUNT"14"EXTRADISCOUNTAMOUNT"0"TOTALITEMSDISCOUNTAMOUNT"0"TOTALAMOUNT"114"SIGNATURES""SIGNATURETYPE""I""VALUE""NA"
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wkVzjelj)

Comment: But how to handle the repeated keys for the arrays? I mean the repeated keys for array are not shown in the output.

Comment: It still doesn't print the key before every array element as shown above. It only prints it once. @MT0

Comment: @kimoturbo It certainly looks like it does [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2MzcNHCE)

Comment: Then why is the number of characters between the target output and the actual output is different? I noticed that the decimal points in numbers are removed. How to fix that? Also, I don't think that's the only difference. What other things could be causing the difference in characters between the two outputs? @MT0

Comment: @kimoturbo Why don't you try some small examples and debug it yourself? Alternatively [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74532387/edit) to put a complete set of rules on how to format the string because at the moment there are no rules and you are asking us to guess at solutions and then telling us that the solutions are wrong (when we don't know what "right" looks like).